# SE API V1.1 documentation, date errata

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, documentation, obsolete

The Stack Exchange API, version 1.1, documentation is ever so slightly confusing wherever Unix timestamps are mentioned (*perhaps any ranges, I haven't dug too deeply*)

[For instance:](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/answers-by-ids)

> **todate** – Unix timestamp of the maximum creation date on a returned item.
> unix epoch date, range *[0, 253,402,300,799]*

It took me a very brief moment to understand what was intended by the italicized part. For clarity, perhaps this should be edited to one of the following:

> ...unix epoch date, *range [0, 253402300799]*
>
> ...unix epoch date, *range [0 .. 253,402,300,799]*
>
> ...unix epoch date, *range [0 - 253,402,300,799]*

Comment: Hm, I don't know how likely it is that the legacy API documentation will be fixed. I don't believe that the [2.x documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) exhibits the same error, but I haven't read through it comprehensively.

Comment: @TimStone Spot on; didn't see it was fixed there. Well, I'll leave this here for the sake of completeness, but you're right.